# Find the best combination of n element from a list that satisfies specific conditions

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools, or-tools

I'm developing a function that solves any combination from an arbitrary list that needs to meet some of condition. A specific case is depicted below:
Given a list of 9 elements

```
[3,2,5,8,9,11,45,12,44],
```

find the best combination of elements so that the **sum of those elements < 90 with the minimum number of element removed**.

I'm thinking about using itertools.combinations or even Google ORTools but not yet come up with the solution. Please share any idea for that, thank you!

Comment: How is that not simply greedy? What's the correct result for that input?

Comment: Your specific case can be solved with window sum on sorted array (`O(n log n)` to sort, `O(n)` to find) - basic greedy algo, so you should provide either more generic kind of condition or explain why this doesn't fit...

Comment: Your wording implies a that you believe there to be a ***singular*** "best solution". But the constraint you give does ***not*** imply that, rather allowing multiple equally valid solutions. For your example, you have a total of 139. Taking away ***any*** of [45,5] through to [45,44] thus satisfies your constraint; do you have a preference / tie breaker constraint? For example, removing [44,5] yields the highest remaining total (exactly 90), but taking away [45,44] yields the lowest remaining total, but is much less expensive to find.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "find the best combination of elements so that the sum of those elements < 90 with the minimum number of element removed." What does "best" mean? If I show you two combinations of elements, how will you decide which one is "better"?

Comment: Also, if the list was [4,5,40,44,45] would removing [45,4] be better or worse than removing [44,5]?

Comment: If you want a truely generic approach, rather than code tailored to one particular  problem statement, considered a package called [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), and watch this video; https://youtu.be/C9eXcmWWEyA

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the largest element until it reaches the target:

```
def find_best_combination(lst, target_sum):
    while(sum(lst) > target_sum):
        lst.remove(max(lst))
    return lst

lst = [3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 11, 45, 12, 44]
print(lst)
result = find_best_combination(lst, 90)
print(result)
print(sum(result))
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 11, 45, 12, 44]
[3, 2, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12]
50
```

Comment: Why not just remove the largest numbers until you reach the target sum?

Comment: It is a subset sum problem. It is actually np-hard. Of course, you can brute force it for small cardinality.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Isn't it just `while sum(lst) >= target_sum: lst.remove(max(lst))`?

Comment: @KellyBundy This won't return the largest sum, I thought this is needed.

Comment: @noah1400 That's not currently required anywhere in the OP, so rather than make assumptions I've asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: @noah1400 Hmm, the optimality criterion they stated is just *"minimum number of element removed"*. For that, removing largest first is the way to go.

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right but I thought returning the largest sum is required because in the question the user talked about using itertools

Comment: But the question doesn't currently actually ask that, and your answer doesn't even actually do that. (Your code gives 87 by removing 44,8, my mental arithmetic gives 89 by removing 45,5)

Comment: @MatBailie hmm you're right